# jQuery transform not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, transform

I am building a simple jQuery function to move elements with mousemove. I am trying to use .css('transform', 'translate...'), but somehow I can't get it work.

```js
$(document).on('mousemove', function (ev) {

 var mouseX = ev.originalEvent.pageX;
 var mouseY = ev.originalEvent.pageY;

 $('.followmouse').each(function () {

  var objectX = $(this).offset().left;
  var objectY = $(this).offset().top;

  var diffX = mouseX - objectX;
  var diffY = mouseY - objectY;

  $(this).css('transform', 'translate(' + diffX + ', ' + diffY + ')');

 });

});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.followmouse {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  align-self: center;
  margin: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div class="followmouse"></div>
<div class="followmouse"></div>

</body>
```

I've tried to apply answers from similar questions, but none seemed to work for me. Any ideas?

Comment: *"This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers."* Glad you figured it out, probably best to just use the "delete" link to delete the question.

Comment: It doesn't look like your `transform` property unit values are specified; the  values should be terminated with `px` (to indicate *pixel* unit values being used), or something similar, e.g: your rule should end up looking something like this: `transform: translate(3px, 3px);`, however, it appears as though it may end up looking something like this: `transform: translate(3, 3);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know what you want to achieve here but you've Just to append `px` to your value in translate as `'translate(' + diffX + 'px, ' + diffY + 'px)'`

See below snippet :

```js
$(document).on('mousemove', function (ev) {
  console.log(ev.target,this);
 var mouseX = ev.originalEvent.pageX;
 var mouseY = ev.originalEvent.pageY;

 $('.followmouse').each(function () {

  var objectX = $(this).offset().left;
  var objectY = $(this).offset().top;

  var diffX = mouseX - objectX;
  var diffY = mouseY - objectY;
    console.log(diffX,diffY);
  $(this).css('transform', 'translate(' + diffX + 'px, ' + diffY + 'px)');

 });

});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.followmouse {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  align-self: center;
  margin: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div class="followmouse"></div>
<div class="followmouse"></div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

I forgot to insert units (px) after the variable...